# Properties of (finite) signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Here $\nu$ is a finite signed measure in a measurable space (X,M) and |$\nu$| being its total variation measure. I don't understand why the "sup" part is necessary for this claim.

Comment: Without that $\sup$, the LHS is a number, whereas the RHS is a set. How can they possibly be equal?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos well I mean to ask why can't we just say $|\nu|(E)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\nu (E_{i})|$ since each $E_{i}$ is disjoint from each other...

Comment: And which number is that? For each set $\{E_1,\ldots,E_n\}\subset\mathcal M$, in general you will get a different $\sum_{i=1}^n\bigl|\mu(E_i)\bigr|$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yea but we have E being disjointly partitioned into $E_{i}$'s aren't they...

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that for a signed measure, if $E_1,...,E_n$ are disjoint, then
$$\nu(E)=\sum_{i=1}^n \nu(E_i),$$
and
$$|\nu|(E)=\sum_{i=1}^n |\nu|(E_i).$$
But in general, $|\nu|(E_i)\neq |\nu(E_i)|$.

Nevertheless, you have the result with the supremum.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I misread the question :)